# '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

```
def mnum(num, num2, num3):
    if (num >= num2 and num >= num3):
        return num
    elif (num2 >= num and num2 >= num3):
        return num2
    elif (num3 >= num and num3 >= num2):
        return num3
    else:
        print("You should choose from 1 , 2 , 3 !")
num = print(input('choose from 1 , 2 , 3: '))
num2 = print(input('choose from 1 , 2 , 3 (do not choose the same first one): '))
num3 = print(input('choose from 1 , 2 , 3 (do not choose the same first and seconed one): '))
print(mnum(num , num2 , num3))
```

The error I'm getting is `'>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`.

Comment: `input()` already prints the prompt.  You don't need to call `print()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `print()` outside of your `input()`s. You don't need that. Just remove them and the code will run.
The problem is that `print()` doesn't return anything so when you write `num = print(input(...))`, `num` is assigned `None`

Answer (score 2):

`print` is a function that returns `None`. i.e.:

```
a = print(1)
assert a is None
```

You need to store it in a variable separately. You should also convert the input to integers as the value returned from `input` is a string:

```
num = int(input('choose from 1 , 2 , 3: '))
num2 = int(input('choose from 1 , 2 , 3 (do not choose the same first one): '))
num3 = int(input('choose from 1 , 2 , 3 (do not choose the same first and seconed one): '))

print(num)
print(num2)
print(num3)

print(mnum(num , num2 , num3))
```